# Universal joint not parenting to bone correctly

Tags: rigging

I've been having troubles getting this universal joint rigged. It's mostly alright except for when I move the entire arm. The one piece of the joint will not go along with it no matter what I do. Parenting it to either bone messes up it's location (keeping transform doesn't work).

I know there is another way to do this that involves using bones, however, I would rather not have to convert this joint. If there is not alternative, then I guess I will.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Parenting should work fine, but it is important to set the object origins (rotation pivots) correctly. Some constraints would also help.